# Find a continuous function with given conditions

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, continuity

Let $g : [0 , \infty) \to \Bbb R$ be continuous function such that$\int_{0}^{x^2(1+x)}g(t)dt = x,  \forall x \in [0 , \infty)$ Then find $g(x)$ and $g(2)$

My Attempt:
By using Leibniz rule under integral sign, I get $g(x^3 + x^2)$ = $1\over3{x}^2 + 2x$ so when I take $x = 1$ then I get $g(2)$ = $1\over5$. Am I right ? If I'm not right then help me.

Comment: you should carefully write your proceedure, it is hard to follow nyou

Comment: Hint : let $G$ be the antiderivative of $g$ which has $G(0) = 0$. Write the integral equation in terms of $G$, then take a derivative.

Comment: $g$ that you got isn't continuous at $x=0$. I guess no continuous function on $[0, \infty)$ satisfying conditions in the question exist. If instead we take the lower limit to be a positive number and retain all the conditions in the question, what you did seem to be correct. But you haven't explicitly found out $g(x)$, which I am also curious to see what would be it.

Comment: Is this problem related to integral equation ? I'm surprising, how it is solve with the help of integral equation .

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Comment: @SolubleFish , In voltera integral equation, limits of integration varies from $0$ to $x$ but here limits varies from $0$ to ${x}^3 + {x}^2$. So I'm unable to solve above question. Please answer my question.

Comment: The equation constrains some integral of the unknown function $g$ : it is called an integral equation, though you are right it is not the *Volterra* integral equation. I'm writing an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g : [0,+\infty) \to \mathbb R$ be a solution and $G : [0,+\infty) \to \mathbb R$ be its antiderivative which has $G(0) = 0$. Then, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have :
$$\forall x\in [0,+\infty), G(x^3 + x^2) = x$$
Taking the first derivative of both sides, we get :
$$\forall x\in [0,+\infty), (3x^2 + 2x) g(x^3+x^2) = 1$$

The function $x\in [0,+\infty) \to (x^2+1)x \in [0,+\infty)$ is a continuous bijection :  it has a continuous inverse $\varphi$. Then, $g$ is given by :
$$\forall x \in [0,+\infty), g(x) =\frac{1}{\varphi(x) (3\varphi(x)+2)}$$

The value you get for $g(2)$ is correct, since $(1^2+1)1 = 2$ implies $\varphi(2) = 1$.

*Remark* : I am not sure what you mean in the OP by "using the Leibniz rule under integral sign".